# Three.js skybox not loading completely or at all

Tags: image, three.js, loading, skybox

I inserted a skybox in my Three.js canvas like this:

```
// SkyBox
var urls = [
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/pos-x.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/neg-x.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/pos-y.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/neg-y.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/pos-z.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/neg-z.jpg'
]
window.cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls);
cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
window.shader = THREE.ShaderLib['cube']; 
shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = cubemap; 

window.skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
    uniforms: shader.uniforms,
    depthWrite: false,
    side: THREE.BackSide
});

window.skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000),
    skyBoxMaterial
);

skybox.position.set(0, 200, 0);

scene.add(skybox);
```

My problem is that the images do not load at all or completely depending on the browser.

On Chrome, they are nearly always loaded (sometimes one face is not loaded). On Firefox, they are nearly never loaded the first time (I get a black background). I tried to add a settimer to wait for a complete load but it does not change anything. It seems they are loaded or not  or partially, but there is no need to wait.

Did I do something wrong? Is there a specific format to have for the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy in fact. 'loadTextureCube' has a callback function. The code has to be change to :

```
var urls = [
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/pos-x.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/neg-x.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/pos-y.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/neg-y.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/pos-z.jpg',
    themePath + 'assets/img/sky/neg-z.jpg'
]
window.cubemap = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube(urls, undefined, function() { 

    cubemap.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
    window.shader = THREE.ShaderLib['cube']; 
    shader.uniforms['tCube'].value = cubemap; 

    window.skyBoxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
        fragmentShader: shader.fragmentShader,
        vertexShader: shader.vertexShader,
        uniforms: shader.uniforms,
        depthWrite: false,
        side: THREE.BackSide
    });

    window.skybox = new THREE.Mesh(
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000, 1000, 1000),
        skyBoxMaterial
    );

    skybox.position.set(0, 200, 0);

    scene.add(skybox);

});
```