# CubeTextureLoader not loading skybox in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I cannot for the life of me figure out what I am doing wrong here.  I'm trying to load a simple skybox and I'm getting nothing. I've tried to look up the answer, but most use `THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube` which has since been deprecated.  I can't seem to find any examples on the new `THREE.CubeTextureLoader`.

Note: I am using this in conjunction with the three.js youtube loader example...
http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_youtube

```
var loader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
textureArray = ['galaxy_starfield.png', 'galaxy_starfield1.png', 'galaxy_starfield2.png', 'galaxy_starfield3.png', 'galaxy_starfield4.png', 'galaxy_starfield5.png'];
loader.setPath('./img/');
var textureCube = loader.load([
    'galaxy_starfield.png', 'galaxy_starfield1.png', 'galaxy_starfield2.png', 'galaxy_starfield3.png', 'galaxy_starfield4.png', 'galaxy_starfield5.png'
]);

var skyMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x444444,
    map: new THREE.TextureLoader(textureArray),
    opacity: 0,
    transparent: true
});

var skyGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2000, 2000, 2000);

var skyMesh = new THREE.Mesh(skyGeometry, skyMaterial);
scene.add(skyMesh);
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm not getting any errors (just an error from ad blocker).  Is it possible there is an error with CubeTextureLoader?

All these posts use ImageUtils.loadTextureCube:

[comparing methods of creating skybox material in three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310880/comparing-methods-of-creating-skybox-material-in-three-js)

[Three.js skybox not loading completely or at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519547/three-js-skybox-not-loading-completely-or-at-all)

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Textures/Texture) specifies (also with an example), the material should be created with an `envMap` property that should be set to your loaded `cubeTexture`.

```
var skyMaterial= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: 0xffffff,
    envMap: textureCube,
    side: THREE.BackSide
} );
```

The `side` property is used so that the material will be seen from inside the cube.

Also, I dont think its necessary to make your skybox that big. Just make it follow your cameras position before every render.

```
skyBox.position.copy(camera.position);
```

Comment: Just did all of those things. Still nothing :(

Comment: @mattyfew [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKZgeP?editors=0010) is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when when I worked on it and I found the solution. Basically, TextureLoader works on-screen width height behalf, so if you are working on 1920x1080, try this:

```
import sun from ’ ‘https://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/screen/heic1310a.jpg’';
const cubeTextureLoader = new THREE.CubeTextureLoader();
scene.background = cubeTextureLoader.load([sun, sun, sun, sun, sun, sun]);
```

or any image whose width is 1280px and height is also 1280px. This will work.